# Spring Security and EnableGlobalMethodSecurity

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am trying to use Spring Security java config with annotations. Basically I would like use a combination of annotation approach with static configurations.

```
http
    .authorizeRequests()
    .anyRequest().authenticated()
```

And

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping({"/version", "/*/version"})
@PermitAll
public class VersionController {
// Implementation
}
```

Shortly I want that `@PermitAll` must have precedence over other voters. Is it possible to use `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(jsr250Enabled = true)` for this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed my view a little bid and started to think another solution. If I can know my controllers before spring security started, I can configure it by processing them. Basically I created a processor and little bid simplified version of my implementation is:

```
@Component
public class PermitAllProcessor {

   private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PermitAllProcessor.class);

   @Autowired
   AbstractHandlerMethodMapping abstractHandlerMethodMapping;


   public String[] process() {
      Map<RequestMappingInfo, HandlerMethod> handlerMethods = abstractHandlerMethodMapping.getHandlerMethods();
      ArrayList<String> urls = Lists.newArrayList();
      for(Map.Entry<RequestMappingInfo, HandlerMethod> entry : handlerMethods.entrySet()) {
         PermitAll annotation = getPermitAll(entry.getValue());
         if(annotation != null) {
            Set<String> patterns = entry.getKey().getPatternsCondition().getPatterns();
            urls.addAll(patterns);
         }
      }
      logger.info("Permitted urls as follows: {}",
                    StringUtils.collectionToDelimitedString(urls, ",", "[", "]"));
      return urls.toArray(new String[urls.size()]);
   }

   private PermitAll getPermitAll(HandlerMethod value) {
      PermitAll annotation = value.getMethodAnnotation(PermitAll.class);
      if(annotation == null){
         annotation = value.getBeanType().getAnnotation(PermitAll.class);
      }
      return annotation;
   }
}
```

And basically

```
 .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers(permitAllProcessor.process()).permitAll()
    .anyRequest().authenticated();
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand it's not possible to achieve your goal using method security, because request processing pipeline looks as follows:

1. Spring Security applies web security rules
2. `DispatcherServlet` selects a hanlder method
3. Method security is applied to handler method, if it has security annotations

However, you can try to achieve it using different approach (not tested):

- Extract metadata for all handler methods as described [here](http://www.java-allandsundry.com/2012/03/endpoint-documentation-controller-for.html)
- Use it to configure Spring Secuirty
  For example, select `RequestMappingInfo`s for all methods that have your custom `@PermitAll` annotation and create a custom `RequestMatcher` that would return `true` for requests to these methods. Then configure Spring Security to allow everyone to access URLs that match the said matcher.

Comment: As the Spring Security project lead, I can confirm this is not possible with the existing infrastructure. In my option, the best approach would be to not use the URL based security at all and create a custom MethodSecurityMetadataSource that defaults to requiring the user to be authenticated. This ensures all security is taking place on the methods. Refer to Jsr250MethodSecurityMetadataSource for an example. You can extend GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration and override methodSecurityMetadataSource to specify your custom MethodSecurityMetadataSource.

Comment: @RobWinch I was considering that adding JSR250 might do trick. That is why I reported SEC-2432 as well.

Comment: @axtavt Does it mean when spring security applies web  security rules, I do not have handler information? I think that I am missing something because I have checked that a voting has necessary information such as method annotations. I would be glad that If you can expand a little bid more. I was considering add Jsr250Voter to my voter deciders.